# How to get value from spinner in android ?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, sms

How to get values from drop down menu and use them in body of new message to be send.

Following is my code,

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
String phoneNo = editPhoneNum.getText().toString();
             String sms = editSMS.getText().toString();
             try {
                     SmsManager smsManager =    SmsManager.getDefault();
                     smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


             }
```

Comment: final  label+sms and pass it.

Comment: do i need to pass it in the smsManager

Answer (score 2):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // On selecting a spinner item
            String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   //make this as field atribute
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");    
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                list.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `String label` and `String  phoneNo` variables globally and then pass it in your message body.
 Append your spinner item in your `sms` string.

Supposing your class code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String phoneNo,sms,label;

      @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            ............................. 
          phoneNo = editPhoneNum.getText().toString();
         sms = editSMS.getText().toString() + label;
         try {
                 SmsManager smsManager =    SmsManager.getDefault();
                 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


         }
```

Comment: Yes it helps. @ GrlsHu

Comment: Vote the answer if it helped you. @user3172071

Answer (score 1):

```
   String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getvalue();
```

`getvalue()`.. according to location ur going getting only position. you have to get value yes use what value u want to get insted of `getvalue()` function name

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look how we can do this i am sending example to you.
please look here

```
   @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

the full example is shown here as follows.

AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List&lt;String&gt; categories = new ArrayList&lt;String&gt;();
        categories.add("Automobile");
        categories.add("Business Services");
        categories.add("Computers");
        categories.add("Education");
        categories.add("Personal");
        categories.add("Travel");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt; dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt;(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Text Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Category:"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

    <!-- Spinner Element -->
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm using sqLite to store and retrive data from drop down menu. The thing i need to do is to use the selected item from drop down menu and use it in body of new message

Comment: than what you can do is  make String label and String phoneNo variables globally and then pass it in your message where you need.